# Enzyme simulate change input don't change value on React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-hooks, enzyme

i'm trying write test's with Jest and Enzyme on React. But on call `.simulate('change')` function the value keep `NULL` and don't change to expected value `miqueias@gmail.com`.
My App.jsx:

```
const App = () => {
    const [username, setUsername] = React.useState(null);
    const [password, setPassword] = React.useState(null);
    const handleChange = (event) => {
        setUsername(event.target.value);
    };
    return (
        <div
            style={{
                height: "100vh",
                display: "flex",
                flexDirection: "column",
                justifyContent: "center",
                alignItems: "center",
            }}
        >
            <input
                type="email"
                id="email"
                value={username}
                onChange={handleChange}
            />
            <input
                type="password"
                id="password"
                value={password}
                onChange={(event) => setPassword(event.target.value)}
            />
            <button>Enviar</button>
        </div>
    );
};
export default App;
```

My App.test.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import {
    configure,
    shallow,
} from 'enzyme';
import App from '../App';
configure({
    adapter: new Adapter()
});
it('<App/> state input', () => {
    const email = shallow(<App/>).find('#email');
    email.simulate('change', {
        target: {
            value: 'miqueias@gmail.com'
        }
    });
    expect(email.prop('value')).toEqual('miqueias@gmail.com');
})
```

Return error on `npm test` command:

```
Expected: "miqueias@gmail.com"
Received: null
```

Answer (score 6):

I just had the same error. Investigating in the link is better explained but basically you have to do a re-find to update the values ​​...

```
cont wrapper = shallow(<App/>);
let email = wrapper.find('#email');

email.simulate('change', {
    target: {
        value: 'miqueias@gmail.com'
    }
});

email = wrapper.find('#email');
expect(email.prop('value')).toEqual('miqueias@gmail.com');
```

Source: https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/blob/master/docs/guides/migration-from-2-to-3.md#element-referential-identity-is-no-longer-preserved

Comment: Didn't work for me unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

For those who got multiple inputs just like mine.
I had the same issue and found the working solution from [wrapper not updated after simulate('change'). #1999](https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/issues/1999#issuecomment-491634796)

Just add `name` or `id` to distinguish between being-tested components:

```
.simulate('change', {target: {name: 'inputFirstName', value: 'value'}})
```

It took me quite a long time on this, so hope it helps someone here...

Comment: Sure helped me! Thanks.

Comment: Didn't work for me unfortunately.